# build ANE Share/SMS/Toast extension for android

Tags: android, actionscript, air, air-native-extension

I'm new to AIR for Android development and can't seem to get past building the ANE sharing/SMS/Toast native extension for my android development in ActionScript on AIR for Android. I have downloaded the ANE source from http://extensionsforair.com/extensions/ssd-android-extensions/. I have 3 folders: AndroidExtensions, AndroidExtensions_Demo and AndroidExtensions_Native.

While the AndroidExtensions folder contains ActionScript Files which I have successfully linked to and referenced in my ActionScript document, I'm thinking I need to build the contents of the AndroidExtensions_Native folder into an ANE file to place it in my ActionScript Document Classpath for the application i building.

I have downloaded and setup AdobeAIRSDK so I can use adt.bat to build the ane. having gone thru the documentation and running

```
adt -package -target ane myext.ane
```

produces an error - "not enough arguments" .

I would be grateful if someone can help me out as I don't have much time on my hands especially someone who has used the ANE sharing/SMS/Toast for ActionScript AIR development on Android.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need a lot more information in your packaging command than you have specified.

You should probably read through the following [help guide](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/extensions/WSf00ab63af761f170-168f6f2a129378b935d-8000.html) from Adobe. The eventual command should look something more like this:

```
adt -package <signing options> -target ane MyExtension.ane MyExt.xml -swc MyExtension.swc 
    -platform iPhone-ARM -platformoptions platformiOSARM.xml 
        foo.a abc/x.framework lib.o -C platform/ios . 
    -platform default -C platform/default library.swf
```